# Can I rewrite this SQL to remove repetitive code?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm currently using the below SQL to produce some stats from one of our databases, however the 2 initial temp tables created, use an almost identical SELECT statement.

Is it possible to rewrite this and avoid using 2 almost identical statements?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ QUERY
DECLARE         @StartDate  DATE,
                @EndDate    DATE
SELECT          @StartDate  = ('2015-08-20'),
                @EndDate    = DateAdd(day,1,@StartDate) 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Create Temp Tables
------------------------------------------------ #Submitted
SELECT DISTINCT(e.[EmployeeId])
INTO [#Submitted]
FROM [Activity] a
INNER JOIN [Employee] e ON e.[EmployeeId] = a.[EmployeeId]
INNER JOIN [ActivityTypeLookup] atl ON atl.[ActivityTypeID] = a.[ActivityTypeId]
WHERE e.[EmployeeId] > 1
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        AND atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 22 -- 22 = Submit Command
        AND a.[TimeStamp] >= @StartDate
        AND a.[TimeStamp] < @EndDate
        AND e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
------------------------------------------------ #LoggedIn
SELECT DISTINCT(e.[EmployeeId])
INTO [#LoggedIn]
FROM [Activity] a
INNER JOIN [Employee] e ON e.[EmployeeId] = a.[EmployeeId]
INNER JOIN [ActivityTypeLookup] atl ON atl.[ActivityTypeID] = a.[ActivityTypeId]
WHERE e.[EmployeeId] > 1
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        AND atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 1 -- 1 = Signed In
        AND a.[TimeStamp] >= @StartDate
        AND a.[TimeStamp] < @EndDate
        AND e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- / Create Temp Tables

------------------------------------------------ Output Data
SELECT DISTINCT e.[EmployeeKey],
       e.[FirstName],
       e.[LastName],
       [Description] = CASE
                            WHEN s.[EmployeeId] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Submitted Command' 
                            WHEN li.[EmployeeId] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Logged In' ELSE 'Not Logged In' 
                        END,
        e.[Email]
FROM [Employee] e
INNER JOIN [Activity] a ON e.[EmployeeId]=a.[EmployeeId]
LEFT JOIN [#Submitted] s ON e.[EmployeeId]=s.[EmployeeId]
LEFT JOIN [#LoggedIn] li ON e.[EmployeeId]=li.[EmployeeId]
WHERE e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        ORDER BY [Description]

------------------------------------------------ Drop Temp Tables
DROP TABLE #LoggedIn
DROP TABLE #Submitted
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ / QUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `WHERE` clause you can filter both `ActivityTypeID`, then do your `CASE`..`WHEN` on that ID, in the following way:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ QUERY
DECLARE         @StartDate  DATE,
                @EndDate    DATE
SELECT          @StartDate  = ('2015-08-20'),
                @EndDate    = DateAdd(day,1,@StartDate) 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Create Temp Table
------------------------------------------------ #SubmittedLogged
SELECT DISTINCT e.[EmployeeId], atl.[ActivityTypeID]
INTO [#SubmittedLogged]
FROM [Activity] a
INNER JOIN [Employee] e ON e.[EmployeeId] = a.[EmployeeId]
INNER JOIN [ActivityTypeLookup] atl ON atl.[ActivityTypeID] = a.[ActivityTypeId]
WHERE e.[EmployeeId] > 1
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        AND ((atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 1) OR (atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 22 )) -- 1 = Signed in, 22 = Submit Command
        AND a.[TimeStamp] >= @StartDate
        AND a.[TimeStamp] < @EndDate
        AND e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- / Create Temp Table

------------------------------------------------ Output Data
SELECT DISTINCT e.[EmployeeKey],
       e.[FirstName],
       e.[LastName],
       [Description] = CASE
                            WHEN sl.[ActivityTypeID] = 22 THEN 'Submitted Command' 
                            WHEN sl.[ActivityTypeID] = 1 THEN 'Logged In' ELSE 'Not Logged In' 
                        END,
        e.[Email]
FROM [Employee] e
INNER JOIN [Activity] a ON e.[EmployeeId]=a.[EmployeeId]
LEFT JOIN [#SubmittedLogged] sl ON e.[EmployeeId]=sl.[EmployeeId]
WHERE e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        ORDER BY [Description]

------------------------------------------------ Drop Temp Table
DROP TABLE #SubmittedLogged
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following script
You do not need the temp tables as I can see
Sorry, if there is some syntax errors :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.[EmployeeKey],
       e.[FirstName],
       e.[LastName],
       [Description] = CASE
                            WHEN atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 22 THEN 'Submitted Command' 
                            WHEN atl.[ActivityTypeID] = 1 THEN 'Logged In' 
                            ELSE 'Not Logged In' 
                        END,
        e.[Email]
FROM [Employee] e
INNER JOIN [Activity] a ON e.[EmployeeId]=a.[EmployeeId]
INNER JOIN [ActivityTypeLookup] atl ON atl.[ActivityTypeID] = a.[ActivityTypeId]
WHERE e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
        AND e.[EmployeeTypeId] = 1
        AND a.[ImpersonatorId] > 1
        and atl.[ActivityTypeID] IN (1, 22)
        AND a.[TimeStamp] >= @StartDate
        AND a.[TimeStamp] < @EndDate
        AND e.[LeavingDate] IS NULL
        ORDER BY [Description]
```